# How to `cd` into directory with the name `-`?

Tags: bash, cd

Here is an example. I'm creating a directory named `-` and I can't `cd` into it. The command `cd -` returnes me to the previous directory. And I'm a bit supprised that `cd "-"` works the same way. I can enter that directory using the full path `~/-`, but is there other way?

```
user@server:~$ cd /tmp
user@server:/tmp$ cd
user@server:~$ mkdir -
user@server:~$ cd -
/tmp
user@server:/tmp$ cd
user@server:~$ cd "-"
/tmp
user@server:/tmp$ cd ~/-
user@server:~/-$
```

Comment: `mv -- - reasonable-name; cd reasonable-name; (cd ..; mv reasonable-name -)`.  Although I would recommend skipping the last step. ;)

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53017

Answer (score 30, accepted):

use instead

```
cd ./-
```

if you are in the directory above.

Answer (score 14):

or like this:

```
cd -- -/
```

Adding a `/` at the end of a file name ensures that the file is treated as a directory.

Comment: without `--` there is error: 'bash: cd: -/: invalid option'

Comment: Ugh, could have sworn I actually tried that why going through the options.

Comment: [brennanenanen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116076/4411648) was made about 3 hours earlier.

Comment: but brennanenanen's answer isn't the same as this answer

Answer (score 7):

`cd -- ./-`
should do the trick :)

It treats everything after the `--` as not a command.

Comment: Hm. But `cd -- -` does not work.

Comment: as @dev-null said I think it's the `./-` that actually makes it work.

Comment: then `--` does not do anything.

Comment: true, I looked at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/462739/how-to-cd-into-a-directory-with-this-name-2-starting-with-the-hyphen) when I was answering. Sorry about that.